# How to have optional OUTPUT parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, cobol

I have a dynamic stored procedure, which I'm using to run multiple select queries. I have defined something like below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DYNAMIC                     
   (IN   IN_COLUMN1                VARCHAR(150), 
    IN   IN_COLUMN2                VARCHAR(500), 
    IN   IN_COLUMN3                VARCHAR(500), 
    IN   IN_COLUMN4                CHAR(08),     
    IN   IN_COLUMN5                DATE,     
    IN   IN_COLUMN6                CHAR(05),     
    OUT  OUT_COLUMN1               CHAR(01),     
    OUT  OUT_COLUMN2               DEC(4,0),     
    OUT  OUT_COLUMN3               DEC(4,0),     
    OUT  OUT_COLUMN4               CHAR(04), 
    OUT  OUT_COLUMN5               DATE
```

The problem here, when I run Query1, I will have input passed from COBOL DB2 program in IN_COLUMN1,IN_COLUMN2,IN_COLUMN3 and OUTPUT will be fetched into OUT_COLUMN1. I will initialize all INPUT in program, Due to the other OUTPUT parameters like OUT_COLUMN2,OUT_COLUMN3,OUT_COLUMN4 and OUT_COLUMN5 will have null, I'm getting SQLCODE "-305".

To fix this I tried to set OUTPUT parameters to default like below and got error while deploying.

```
OUT  OUT_COLUMN2               DEC(4,0) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Is there any way to handle this. I'm using COBOL to call the stored procedure running in DB2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming IBM Enterprise COBOL,

To handle null values in COBOL host variables in SQL you need to assign a "null indicator" for each nullable variable.

See: [Using host variables in SQL Statements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_determinenulltruncated.html) (with examples in COBOL).

The null indicator will typically be negative if the result variable is null.

By default, all parameters to a DB2 for z/OS Native SQL Stored Procedure are nullable. ([Db2 for z/OS 12.0.0 - Creating Native SQL Procedures](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createproceduresqlnative.html))

For other ways of solving what I perceive is the task at hand,

Whilst I think at least DB2 User-defined Functions may support [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), stored procedures does not. That could have been an alternative.

Otherwise might I suggest returning a dynamic result set from your stored procedure? Then it would be up to the caller of the stored procedure to handle different configurations of the result sets, which is totally doable in COBOL.

Regarding UDF Overloading:

"A schema can contain several functions that have the same name but each of which have a different number of parameters or parameters with different data types. Also, a function with the same name, number of parameters, and types of parameters can exist in multiple schemas."

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_functionresolution.html

Hope it was to some help.

Comment: Thanks It worked, But I had to use NULL indicator for all the OUTPUT fields, Even if the field is defined as NOT NULL.